# Shopware : how to show shop information in theme?

Tags: shopware

I can get shop name with `{config name=shopName}` but what about other info such as address etc. I am referring to latest version of Shopware 5.2

Answer (score 2):

For the address you can use the following code:

```
{config name=address}
```

Here are some other configs:

```
{config name=bankAccount}
{config name=company}
{config name=mail}
```

You can get names from the database (table name is "s_core_config_elements").